# JaCoCo shows 0% coverage, even all tests had passed

Tags: android, android-testing, jacoco, androidx

1. I have written some test cases under `androidTest` directory.
2. I am using androidx (`testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`)
3. added dependencies:

   `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'`

   `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'`
4. added JaCoCo as dependency, as well.
5. When I run `createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport` Gradle task, all the test cases run successfully but coverage is 0% in report

I am guessing that is due to this error:

> V/InstrumentationResultParser: Error: Failed to generate Emma/JaCoCo coverage.
>   V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1

Comment: you might not have defined the correct `classDirectories`; verify this once.

Comment: I have also define dir.
    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])

Answer (score 5):

Google just redirected me to my own answer ...

As it turned out, for Android projects one (meanwhile) has to use a path alike this:

```
"${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes"
```

In case you may wonder... JaCoCo only works for `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` Java unit tests in `test` (but not  `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` Android integration tests in `androidTest`).

Comment: I have tried your way as well but still same error

`InstrumentationResultParser: Error: Failed to generate Emma/JaCoCo coverage.
09:41:33 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1`

Comment: @Subhan have you verified the path, that the `*.class` files are indeed located there? I've intentionally wrote "something alike", because this might slightly vary, based upon the project's build configuration. You need to use whatever your file-browser tells you to use, not what I suggest. this is only a hint, where to look for them.

Comment: Yes, I have looked and file path according to build directory here. But still no success

Comment: Where should I specify this path? Do you have git dedicated?

Comment: I'm not sure if things have changed or my configuration is wrong, but the given path only contains `databinding` stuff for me. Changing the class directory to `${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug` seems to have helped, kind of. It's still not right, but I hope this can be a hint for someone in the future.