# Gradle task jacoco report generate empty html report file (No class files specified)

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco

I would like to use Jacoco to generate a code coverage report on all my tests (androidTest + UnitTest).

So I implemented a step-by-step script (jacoco.gradle) to create a task that allowed me to generate a report that merged two code coverage reports.

My problem is that the html generated file is empty (in `app\build\jacocoReport\index.html`):

> No class files specified.
>   JaCoCo 0.8.3.201901230119

I execute 'testIntegrationDebugUnitTest' task :

- **androidTest** code coverage report has been created on *app/build/reports/coverage/integration/debug/index.html* and it's ok.
- A 'ec' file has been generated on app\build\outputs\code_coverage\integrationDebugAndroidTest\connected\Pixel_2_API_24(AVD) - 7.0-coverage.ec
- A 'exec' file has been generated on app/build/jacoco/testIntegrationDebugUnitTest.exec

Do you have any idea where my problem comes from? Here is my code:

**jacoco.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "$jacocoVersion"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/jacocoReport")
}

project.afterEvaluate {

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def variantName = variant.name
        def testTaskName = "test${variantName.capitalize()}UnitTest"
        def androidTestCoverageTaskName = "create${variantName.capitalize()}CoverageReport"

        tasks.create(name: "${testTaskName}Coverage", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ["$testTaskName", "$androidTestCoverageTaskName"]) {
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the ${variantName.capitalize()} build."

            reports {
                xml.enabled = false
                html.enabled = true
                html.destination "$buildDir/jacocoReport"
            }

            def excludes = ['**/R*.class',
                            '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                            '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                            '**/*$ViewInjector*.class'
            ]

            def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: excludes)
            def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

            sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
            classDirectories = files([debugTree])
            executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
                    "jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec", "outputs/code_coverage/${variantName}AndroidTest/connected/**/*.ec"
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

**gradle project** :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ext.jacocoVersion = '0.8.3'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacocoVersion"
    }
}

task installGradle(type: Wrapper) {
    group = "*********"
    gradleVersion = '4.10.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: '../scripts/jacoco.gradle'

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name == 'demoDebug' || variant.name == 'evalDebug' || variant.name == 'stagingDebug') {
        project.tasks.getByName('process' + variant.name.capitalize() + 'GoogleServices').enabled = false
        project.tasks.getByName('fabricGenerateResources' + variant.name.capitalize()).enabled = false
    }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***********"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.1'
    testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.25.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JaCoCo shows 0% coverage, even all tests had passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575418/jacoco-shows-0-coverage-even-all-tests-had-passed)

Comment: I Have no InstrumentationResultParser error and no other error. I have only an empty html.

Comment: the report reads `No class files specified` and that's build-tools `28.0.3` with `$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug`. ever checked if there are any `*.class` files present in that `debugTree`?

Comment: In $project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/d I have no debug folder but two folder : integrationDebug and integrationDebugAndroidTest. In the subfolders there are some .classes files.

Comment: I have changed the path of debugTree by another : $project.buildDir/intermediates/javac and now I have a no empty html report file. But the html is composed of only 3 packages.

Comment: I had the same problem. What worked for me was changing the `debugTree` def to: `def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: excludes)`

Comment: @MatPag should post as an answer ; thank you, works for me

Comment: Thanks @MatPag, your solution worked for me. You should add it as an answer :)

Comment: @MatPag this did not worked for me. I added this: 
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: excludes)
But when I run the test coverage command I still get this error: "No class file specified"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a common problem, you need to change the `debugTree` property to:

```
//java compiled classes
def javaTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: fileFilter)
//kotlin compiled classes
def kotlinTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
//...etc...
classDirectories.from = files([javaTree, kotlinTree])
```

`debug` can be any variant, you can use `$variantName` in place of it if you know what you are doing

Comment: I'm guessing that'll just contain kotlin classes. If you have a codebase with a mix of Java and Kotlin, it might miss some coverage for Java files.

Comment: @BenPearson yes, the user was interested specifically in kotlin, by the way I've update my answer to cover both Java and Kotlin sources

Comment: Thanks for the update! That was quick.
It's an Android project, so could contain both Kotlin and Java; I think your answer covers all bases now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you configure jacoco plugin with maven, if true please check the   path of configuration tag.It should be class path of target/classes directory, not the package path.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer